# Java: Why doesn't my recursive sort method work?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, bubble-sort

The recursive sort method I wrote below prints the address ("[I@7852e922") when using a typical sout, I believe that has to do with my returns inside sort(). I've tried to make the method void, but that doesn't seem to work either cause then I need to remove the returns. However, when I finally replace it with this mess, it prints out the array unsorted, so turns out my method is ineffective:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(array2, array2.length-1)));
```

Please go easy on me as I've been severely struggling in programming/recursion due to poor training in my prerequisites & learned a typical bubble sort 10 minutes before writing this. Here is my entire test program:

**TL;DR: What's wrong with my sort method and how should I print it?**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array2[] = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 2, 4};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(array2, array2.length-1)));
}

    static public int[] sort(int[] array, int n) {
    int i = array[n];
    int j = i-1;
    int temp;
    if(n == 0) {
        return array;
    } else if(i < j) {
        temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
        return sort(array, n - 1);
    } else {
        return sort(array, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** After feedback, this is what I'm left with. The test works perfectly, prints my array sorted.  I find that when looking at code for too long, I tend to confuse i with x[i]. However, I'm still having trouble avoiding the use of Arrays.toString() or changing to void sort(). I'll stick with this if I have to. Having said that, I appreciate any further assistance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array2[] = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 2, 4};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(array2, array2.length - 1)));
}

static public int[] sort(int[] array, int lastIndex) {
    int j = lastIndex - 1;
    int temp;
    if (lastIndex == 0) {
        return array;
    } else if (array[lastIndex] < array[j]) {
        temp = array[lastIndex];
        array[lastIndex] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        return sort(array, lastIndex - 1);
    } else if (array[lastIndex] > array[j]) {
        return sort(array, lastIndex - 1);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson note that OP is using `Arrays.toString`

Comment: `int i = array[n];int j = i-1; [...] if(i < j)` - never true.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - please read the whole question. It's not asking how to print the array, it's asking why it prints unsorted.

Comment: Your `else if` and `else` branches do similar work in the recursion. This means you either don't need the `else if` or you have not actually done any sorting

Comment: The reason you have not actually sorted is because you are not doing any swapping of elements. The code you have above for swapping is not doing any work on the array

Comment: @BackSlash I have since long realised my mistake and removed the comment

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints out fine to me, though your code is wrong.

You do not need to use the return value, though it makes no difference as you assign it to the variable again.

Check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-bubble-sort/ for a working recursive example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer. I have comments inline within the code. Hope it helps.

```
    private static int[] sort(int[] array, int lastIndex) {
    if(lastIndex<1) { //If array has only 1 element to be sorted then return array as is.
        return array;
    }
    //move the largest number in the array to the last index of the array;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++) {
        if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
            //swap
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    // now we know lastIndex element is highest, sort other elements by decrementing lastIndex
    return sort(array, lastIndex-1);
}
```

Comment: Wish I'd thought to avoid using 'n'. I kept getting confused as to what this even was. Thanks!

Comment: @revolverocelot1944 , your code will still not run 
for example try with 
    int array2[] = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 2, 4,0,25,12,56,22,11};
 it will result in [0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 11, 25, 12, 56, 22]

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems here. First, you compare indexes(i and j are indexes, they tell you position of member in array). You solve this my comparing values like this:

```
else if(array[j] < array[i]){
     temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = temp;   }
```

Second, written like this it will execute only one iteration of bubble sort so you can only be sure that the lowest value will come up at the start of the array(if you know how bubble sort works). To solve this, you must add one more layer of recursion calls but this time you only call for n - 1 elements of array because you sorted the lowest value for sure.

The other way to solve this problem without changes to your sort method is to call a for loop and execute sort method n times.